React Native - can anyone help why I'm getting this error?
I am getting this error, could anyone help?
import React from "react";
import { View, TouchableWithoutFeedback} from 'react-native';
import Video from 'react-native-video';
import styles from "./styles";
import { useState } from 'react';

const Post = () => {
  const [paused, setPaused] = useState(false);

  const onPlayPausePress = () => {
    setPaused(!paused);
  };


  return (
    <View style = {styles.container}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onPlayPausePress}>
        {/* <> */}
          <Video
            source={{uri: "https://d8vywknz0hvjw.cloudfront.net/fitenium-media-prod/videos/45fee890-a74f-11ea-8725-311975ea9616/processed_720.mp4"}}
            style={styles.video}
            onError={(e) => console.log(e)}
            resizeMode={"cover"}
            repeat={true}
            paused={paused}
          />

        {/* </> */}

      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </View>
  );
}

export default Post;

import { StyleSheet,Dimensions } from "react-native";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    container: {
        width: '100%',
        height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
    },

    video: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        right: 0
    },
})

export default styles;

enter image description here
Hello, I am trying to add the functionality of play pause when clicked and it is giving me a error.
I tried changing tags looking for answers online but nothing.
The error message is:
Exception thrown while executing UI block: -[RCTVideo setOnClick:]: unrecognise selector sent to instance.

This happens after upgrading to 0.73 or above of React Native. You can find the discussion in the following thread.
https://github.com/TheWidlarzGroup/react-native-video/issues/3418
You can solve it by removing 'TouchableWithoutFeedback' which is causing this weird bug. It probably would be fixed in the next release.

Im using 0.74.1 version

@e36_King I meant anything above 0.73. Still were you able to solve it once you removed TouchableWithoutFeedback?

It works.. I think i willl just switch it to android simulator for now.
